# java stream: group by an field and select other as grouping key

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like group by a field a select

Guess this class:

```
public class Person {
   private Name name;
   private Address address;
   ...
}

public class Name {
   private String name;
   private String fatherName;
   private String motherName;
}
```

I'd like to group by `Person.getName().getMotherName()` and select `Person.getName()` as grouping object key.

```
Collection<Person> persons = new ...

Map<Name, List<Person>> group = persons.stream()
  .collect(groupingby(p -> p.getName().getMotherName());
```

As you can see, I'd like to get a `Map<Name, List<Person>>`, instead of a `Map<String, List<Person>>`

Any ideas?

Comment: How would this work? What happens if you have two `Person`s with the same `name` but different `fatherName`? Which `fatherName` would you assign to the `Name` object used as the key for the group containing both?

Comment: Please elaborate *group by `Person.getName().getMotherName()` and select `Person.getName()` as grouping object key.* .. Would two `Name`s be equal if their `motherName`s are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't override `equals()` I can think of this way:

Create a wrapper around `Name` which overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `Name.getMotherName()`:

```
public class NameWrapper {
    private final Name name;
    public NameWrapper(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashcode() {
        return name.getMotherName().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == this) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof NameWrapper)) return false;
        NameWrapper other = (NameWrapper) obj;
        return name.getMotherName().equals(other.name.getMotherName());
    }
}
```

Then you can map the `Person#getName()` to a `NameWrapper` and group by that:

```
Map<NameWrapper, List<Person>> group = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new NameWrapper(p.getName())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Map<Name, List<Person>> group = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName()));
```

And you have to Overide the hashCode and equald in your Name class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // your equals code
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // your hash code
}
```

Comment: I can't override `Name.equals`. Sorry.